# Why can't use LINQ methods on JObject?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json.net

`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` implemented `IEnumerable<T>`, and not explicit implementation, but why can't do this:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var jobj = new JObject();
var xxx = jobj.Select(x => x); //error
foreach(var x in jobj) { } //no error
```

WHY? Thanks.

Comment: @GaurangDave According to the documentation it does implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: @juharr I use other language vs, I don't know the actually error message in english, so I try to translate: "JObject no contain a 'Select' method, and there is no a 'Select' extension method accept JObject type at first argument." also, ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,JToken>>)jobj).Select(x=>x) work fine.

Comment: @ahdung That's really odd.  You shouldn't have to cast to get extension methods to work.

Comment: Note that there are other ways to tell compiler which overload you mean, besides direct casting. For example: `jobj.Select((JToken x) => x);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) implements both `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>` and `IEnumerable<JToken>` (by inheriting from `JContainer`).

Thus you cannot use LINQ (e.g. `Select`) directly since it doesn't know which of the enumerables to 'extend'.

Thus you need to cast first:

```
((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>) jobj).Select(x => x)
```

or:

```
jobj.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>().Select(x => x)
```

or as @Evk pointed out:

```
jobj.Select((KeyValuePair<string, JToken> x) => x)
```